# PHP how to calculate totals only from specific table TYPE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

how to calculate totals only from specific table TYPE, i have table with:

```
NAME   AMOUNT   TYPE

John   $15      cash

Dan    $15      check

Ken    $15      check

Karen  $20      cash

ron    $40      credit
```

---

```
Total   $105

cash     $35 

check    $30

credit   $40
```

---

```
$totalPayments = 0;
$totalCash = 0;
$totalCheck = 0;
$totalCredit = 0;


while($pRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($pResult)) {
    $totalPayments += $pRow["payment_amount"];
```

want to get totals by TYPE

`$totalCash += $pRow["payment_amount"]`;  only Where TYPE `$pRow["payment_type"] = "cash"`

`$totalCheck += $pRow["payment_amount"];` only Where TYPE `$pRow["payment_type"] = "check"`

`$totalCredit += $pRow["payment_amount"];` only Where TYPE `$pRow["payment_type"]= "credit"`

Comment: `WHERE type='credit'` or `GROUP BY type`?

Comment: or, use `if/switch` php statement

Answer (score 4):

You can do it also on mysql

```
select type,sum(amount) from table group by type WITH ROLLUP
```

[see GROUP BY Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use array keys for separate it:

```
$part = array('cash'=>0, 'check'=>0, 'credit'=>0);
// ...
$part[$pRow["payment_type"]] += $pRow["payment_amount"];
```

Or just using `switch`:

```
switch($pRow["payment_type"]) {
  case 'cash': $totalCash += $pRow["payment_amount"];
  // ...
}
```

But better change your SQL to group by types: add `GROUP BY payment_type`

Answer (score 0):

And i think that mysql should do it. If you extract data from mysql, let's mysql take care about it. But if you need just total you don't need write `WITH ROLLUP`
just: `select TYPE, sum(AMOUNT) from table group by TYPE;`